# MYSQL - Delete row based on ID-value in other table

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 2 MySQL-tables:

Customer_buyings:

```
BUY_ID   NUMBER   PLANT_ID    CUSTOMER_ID
  001       5         003          009
  002       1         004          009
  003       2         005          010
```

Plants:

```
PLANT_ID     PLANTNAME
  003          BUXUS
  ...           ...
```

Now I want to delete one specific row from the "customer-buyings"-table.
For example the Plant with ID: 003.But I only have the Customer_ID and the PLANTNAME available in my code.

Im searching for a MySQL-query which will delete the 1st row from the Customer_buyings table based on the Customer_id and Plantname (So I would have to compare plantname with plant_id from the other table).

```
DELETE FROM Customer_buyings
JOIN Plants
ON ...
WHERE ...
AND Customer_id="009"
```

Any suggestions? Because I couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Using joins you need to specify from which tables you want to delete. Do it right after the `delete` like this: `DELETE Customer_buyings FROM Customer_buyings JOIN ...`

Comment: I do not want to delete all the buyings from the specific customer. I want to delete one specific one (For Example only the Buxus (Plant_id: 003) from customer 009); Having only the customer_id and the plantname available

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You  need a proper join and a where

```
DELETE c.* FROM Customer_buyings as c
INNER JOIN Plants as p on c.plant_id = p.plant_id
WHERE p.plantname= 'BUXUS'
AND c.Customer_id="009"
```

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'as c JOIN ...

Comment: I have update the answer with inner join  (strange should work also without)   but abyway  let me know ..and eventually show all the error message .

Comment: When you use `DELETE` with `JOIN`, you need to specify which tables you want to delete from. `DELETE c FROM ...`

Comment: Using the Inner Join and specifying the Customer_buyings table before the "FROM" did the trick. Removing one line now as it should